# Laravel get user post with relationship

Tags: php, laravel

i have two table as `user_blogs` and `users` with this relationship structure

UserBlogs :

```
class UserBlogs extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'blog_content'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserBlogs::class);
    }
}
```

in controller i can get user blogs with this code:

```
$userBlogs = User::find($id)->blogs;
```

and i get can result on output, but why this code dont work and i get error:

```
$userBlogs = auth()->user()->blogs();
```

or

```
$userBlogs = auth()->user()->blogs;
```

migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('blog_title');
        $table->longText('blog_content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `auth()->user->blogs` instead. This accesses the properties instead of the function/query builder.

Comment: @aynber i get error again

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have same structure for user and their posts. Following code works for me :

```
$results = Post::with(['user'])->where('user_id',$user_id);
$posts = $results->get();
```

## Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: You can see my complete code on github. Please find the link https://github.com/sapna-bhayal/post_comment

Comment: Instead of `User::class` use `app\user`

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** because of Eloquent's behavior for deducing table names, you should name your models not plural but singular.

`UserBlogs` should be called `UserBlog` instead.